# Fail when sending email from bash using & (background)

Tags: bash, email

When I'm sending an email using this command:

```
mail -s "export CSV" -a calls.tar mail@mail.pl < text.txt > /dev/null 2>&1
```

everything working fine. But when I'm using `&` at the end of the line :

```
mail -s "export CSV" -a calls.tar mail@mail.pl < text.txt > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

query is running to infinity.

How can I run this query properly?

Comment: I just tried out the same query and it works fine for me. Maybe you should redirect errormessages to some file to find out what is going on in your case?

Comment: infaustus, any more information on what was happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ideally you should try to find what is happening, but if you're in a rush or everything is failing, you can try to just enclose everything in () and run that in the background. This should work.

```
$ ( mail -s "export CSV" -a calls.tar mail@mail.pl < text.txt > /dev/null 2>&1 ) &
```

In any case, you can always use debugging techniques and do your command increasing the complexity little by little to see where it fails.

```
$ mail -s "export CSV" mail@mail.pl &
$ mail -s "export CSV" mail@mail.pl < text.txt &
$ mail -s "export CSV" mail@mail.pl < text.txt > /dev/null &
$ mail -s "export CSV" mail@mail.pl < text.txt > /dev/null 2>&1 &
$ mail -s "export CSV" -a calls.tar mail@mail.pl < text.txt > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

You get the idea. :)

Answer (score 1):

**1.** As pointed out by *psibar* you should try redirecting output to a log:

```
mail -s "export CSV" -a calls.tar mail@mail.pl < text.txt >> /tmp/csv.log 2>&1 &
```

**2.** Are you sure the command never finishes? The expected output would be:

```
user@host:~$ mail -s "export CSV" -a calls.tar mail@mail.pl < text.txt > /dev/null 2>&1 &    
[1] 19266
user@host:~$
```

and after you press `ENTER`:

```
[1]+  Done       mail -s "export CSV" -a calls.tar mail@mail.pl < text.txt > /dev/null 2>&1 &                  
user@host:~$
```

*Note:* `19266` here is the PID of the background process. You can check if it's still running using

```
 ps -ef | grep [1]9266
```